# Its possible to use Twilio Vedio SDK for both Audio and Vedio calls?

Tags: ios, twilio, twilio-video

hai I need to know its possible to use Twilio Vedio SDK for both Audio and Vedio calls??. or I need to use separate SDK?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.
Because there is a separated SDK for audio and video.
SDK: TwilioVoice for audio call
SDK: TwilioVideo for Video call

Comment: Please check this    https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios/issues/126